# Batch File Help : Not able to store the values parsed from .csv file to variables

Tags: windows, batch

I have a .CSV(Comma separated) file, from which I need to extract the values at specific columns and then I need to substring those values. The substring values should be written in output file.

However, when I am trying to put the set statement in for /f loop, the values are not getting stored in variables resulting which subString is not working as expected.

Please find the snippet below and advise:

-suppose abcdefgh is the value at %%d

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION    
for /F "usebackqtokens=1-4*delims=^," %%a in (temp.csv) do (
echo %%d
set _id=%%d
echo _clnt: %!_id!:~5,3%
echo %%a,%%b,%%c,!_clnt! >> output.csv
)
```

Output from Above:

```
abcdefgh
_clnt: ~5,3
```

Expected Output:

```
abcdefgh
_clnt: fgh
```

Comment: Your 5th line should be `set _clnt=!_id:~5,3!`

Comment: Hi, I have tried this, but it gives me output as 'set _clnt=!_id:~5,3!' as it is considering the _id a string and not retaining the value of _id on this set command

Comment: When I run it with the modification I mentioned (plus another `echo _clnt: !_clnt!`) it gives exactly the outcome you showed in your "Expected Outcome", and the value of `_clnt` is also shown in the `output.csv` file. What is it you would like to have happen differently?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION    
for /F "usebackqtokens=1-4*delims=^," %%a in (temp.csv) do (
echo %%d
set id=%%d
set _clnt=!_id:~5,3!
echo _clnt: !_clnt!
echo %%a,%%b,%%c,!_clnt! >> output.csv
)
```

Contents of temp.csv

```
x,y,z,abcdefgh
```

Console output of batch script:

```
abcdefgh
_clnt: fgh
```

Contents of output.csv after running batch script:

```
x,y,z,fgh
```